# How to change data inside the inner for loop in rust, whats the workaround?

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, borrow-checker

New to rust. And I'm stuck.

I have a Vec of Vec of &str (basically a collection of CSV rows, each row is Vec of &str).

I want to iterate over the whole collection, and conditionally change some cell values.

I have tried some approaches with iterator and enumeration() to operate with index.

But in the end, I always have this error -> error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*row` as mutable more than once at a time.

And I can't really find how to do it. What's the workaround?

```rust
    //iterate over the collection of rows
    for row in &mut raw_data_rows[0..] {
        //iterate over row cells
        for item in &mut row[0..] {
            //if cell == "n/a"
            if item.to_string() == "n/a" {
                //change it to something else
                todo!(); //change the value of the item
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see any problem with that.
I just made the iterations explicit with `.iter_mut()`.

Note that I'm not certain `&str` is what you want here.
Using `String` would allow mutating their content, not just replacing them.

As requested in a comment, here is why I find these iterations explicit :

- `v.iter_mut()` means « at each iteration I want to obtain an exclusive (mutable) reference to the next element ».
- `v.iter()` means « at each iteration I want to obtain a shared (non-mutable) reference to the next element ».
- `v.into_iter()` means « at each iteration I want to consume/extract the next element » (`v` should not be usable after that).
- Iterating directly on `v` implicitly calls `v.into_iter()` which should *consume* the elements but if `v` is not a value but a reference to a container, this will behave as `v.iter()` which is quite confusing in my opinion.
  That's why I try to always be explicit about my intention when I iterate over a sequence.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut raw_data_rows = vec![
        vec!["aa", "bb", "cc"],
        vec!["dd", "n/a", "ee"],
        vec!["ff", "gg", "hh"],
    ];
    for row in raw_data_rows.iter_mut() {
        for item in row.iter_mut() {
            if *item == "n/a" {
                *item = "NEW_ITEM"
            }
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", raw_data_rows);
}
/*
[["aa", "bb", "cc"], ["dd", "NEW_ITEM", "ee"], ["ff", "gg", "hh"]]
*/
```

Comment: As a Rust newbie I have a question: why did you have to explicitly specify `iter_mut()`? What information would omitting it hide?

Comment: @prog-fh thanks! it works. I think it was one of my first approaches. Maybe I was missing dereferences and have started to dig in the wrong direction =)